# Importing mysql database into Oracle OCI Ubuntu instance

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-cloud

I recently spun up a Ubuntu instance on Oracle OCI (https://cloud.oracle.com) to host a Laravel application.  I need to be able to import a large-ish mysql database, but every time I try, it hangs up the instance after a few minutes.  I've tried various methods, but the same thing happens each time.

These methods work on my local MacBook but not on the instance:

`mysql -u root -p mydatabase < mydatabase.sql`

`gunzip < mydatabase.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p mydatabase`

The database is roughly 1GB when unzipped from a 147.5MB file.

**Details of the instance:**

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- RAM: 1GB
- Disk: 45GB 13GB used
- Mysql: Ver 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu)

Comment: Does ORACLE have the gunzip software available to use?  Where is the binary?  ( What folder )?

Comment: Yes, gunzip is available, and I've tried it with smaller databases.  It hangs the system with larger files.

By "the binary", I assume you mean the .gz file?  It's in ~/tmp.

Comment: Have you tried completing gunzip operation and then use your running MySQL instance to import your 1G of data from the MySQL Command Prompt?

Comment: Yes.  That's why I was trying piping from gunzip to mysql.

Comment: You may find that separate operations for this volume of data will allow you to be more frequently successful.